# OpenId with java web app - should I use RPXNow?

Tags: java, openid

So I have been trying for a days to get OpenId working right on my Google App Engine Java website.

I'm thinking maybe I should just use RPXNow. What are the downsides to using RPXNow?

Comment: http://blog.nerdbank.net/2009/01/why-using-rpxnow-is-bad-idea.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read that post, which is over a year old, PLEASE read the full post and Larry's (Larry Drebes, co-founder) response as he pointed out several flaws to the writers' assertions.  RPXNow is a fantastic and MUCH easier fit for your application than trying to do everything on your own using the OpenID libraries.  Try the basic version for free and see for yourself.  There are some features that are turned off for the basic version (e.g. social publishing), but the implementation is the same AND you can see for yourself how easy it is to wire RPX/Authentication into your application.  When I first joined the company I wired up a simple PHP application to use RPX (as a complete newby to RPX) in about 3 hours.  It'll take more time if you're folding into an existing app, but much less time than doing it all on your own.  Oh, and since you're using the Google App Engine, you'll want to check out this recipe written by Brian Ellin, our Product Manager:  http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/accept-google-aol-yahoo-myspace-facebook-and-openid-logins/

HTH - John

John Beutler
Solution Engineer
JanRain, Inc.
johnb@janrain.com
Mobile: 503-860-9804 | Fax: 888-563-3082
Twitter: @rpxnow and @janrain
Facebook: www.facebook.com/rpxnow

Increase registrations, engage users, and grow your brand with RPX
Learn more at www.rpxnow.com